# Logback messages are getting mixed up in multithreaded dropwizard service scenario

Tags: logback, dropwizard

We have a multithreaded service where some individual log messages are getting corrupted when another thread writes to the log at the same time.  How can I prevent this from happening?

We are using worker threads to make REST service calls, receive, and process a response.  While doing so, we write to the log, using logback, the default logging engine in dropwizard.

specific case that I'm looking at is when a thread throws an exception, we log the stack trace.  What I see is that the trace is cut in half by entries from at least one other thread:

Example

```
   [pool-4-thread-13] Error!
         stack trace line 1
   [pool-4-thread-17] Event 1 happened
   [pool-4-thread-17] Event 2 happened
         stack trace line 2
         stack trace line 3
         stack trace line 4
```

What I expected to see in the log was something like this:

```
   [pool-4-thread-13] Error!
         stack trace line 1
         stack trace line 2
         stack trace line 3
         stack trace line 4
   [pool-4-thread-17] Event 1 happened
   [pool-4-thread-17] Event 2 happened
```

config.yaml

```
server:

  adminContextPath: /admin
  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 9193

  applicationContextPath: /

  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 9192
      maxRequestHeaderSize: 64KiB

  requestLog:
    timeZone: UTC

    appenders:
      - type: file
        currentLogFilename: ./logs/service-requests.log
        archive: true

        # When the log file rotates, the archived log will be renamed to this and gzipped. The
        # %d is replaced with the previous day (yyyy-MM-dd). Custom rolling windows can be created
        # by passing a SimpleDateFormat-compatible format as an argument: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh}".
        archivedLogFilenamePattern: ./logs/service-requests.log.%d.log.gz

        # The number of archived files to keep.
        archivedFileCount: 30

logging:
  level: INFO

  loggers:
    # We only care about warning log messages from the apache libraries, like hadoop, zookeeper, and phoenix
    org.apache: WARN

  appenders:
    - type: file
      timeZone: UTC
      currentLogFilename: ./logs/service-log.log
      archive: true
      archivedFileCount: 30
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: ./logs/service-log-%d.log.gz
      logFormat: "[%date{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}] [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message %n"
```

Comment: There is a probably a cause and a solution.  But it really depends on how you have your logging set up.  How about posting your logbook.xml and other relevant information?

Comment: posted the config.yaml file which is used by dropwizard to configure logback

Comment: First question: What DW version is in use? I never seen this in my apps and sometimes I have up to 200 Threads writing at the same time...

Comment: haven't had a chance to go back to this yet.. each worker thread uses the same static instance of a logger-- could this be the issue? because each thread uses the same logger instance, they are all colliding